# Plotting functions in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to plot a function in Julia, but keep getting errors. I don't understand what is wrong. The input and output of $\varphi$ is a scalar. I've used `x=1530:1545` and still get an error-- can anyone enlighten me? I am very confused.

I am using Julia 0.7.[image]

EDIT:

I got it to work with a slight modification--I changed
`x = 1530:1545`
 added the following two lines

`y = t.(x)
plot(x,y)`

Why did I have to do this though?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `0.7` and not `1.0` (long term) or `1.2` (latest)?

Comment: Yes, because IJulia/Jupyter wouldn't install properly-- specifically IJulia. I think this is an ongoing issue?

Comment: What is your current version of PyPlot?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't need the `pyplot()` function call - that is syntax from a different plotting package (called "Plots")

Comment: As @MichaelK.Borregaard said, it looks like you're trying to use the Plots.jl syntax in PyPlot.jl - if you replace `PyPlot` by `Plots`, your code should work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is currently not available in `PyPlots.jl`, if you would like to have it in the future, your best bet is to file an issue.
However, you can get that functionality via `Plots.jl` and using `PyPlot` as a backend.
It would look like this (I'll take a simpler function):

```
using Plots
pyplot()

start_point = 0
end_point = 10
plot_range = start_point:end_point
plot(sqrt,plot_range) # if you want the function exactly at 0,1,2,3...
plot(plot_range,sqrt) # works the same
plot(sqrt,start_point,end_point) # automatically chooses the interior points
```